# Nested expressions in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an array `$scope.colourname =['blue','green'];` 
I have a json value `item.color` which has outputs of 0 and 1 
I want to change a background color as per the json value as blue or green

```
<div id="header_pic" ng-style="myStyle={'background-color':'{{colourname[**value**]}}'}">
    <div id="header_pic_text">
     F
    </div>
</div>
```

How to change `ng-style` **background** **value** like `ng-style="myStyle={'background-color':'{{colourname[{{item.color}}]}}'}"`

Is there any way to nest the expressions as above.
The above code is not working.

But this `ng-style="myStyle={'background-color':'{{colourname[0]}}'}"` AND `ng-style="myStyle={'background-color':'{{colourname[1]}}'}"` alone works as the colourname is 0 or 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `{}`, like this:

```
ng-style="myStyle={'background-color':colourname[item.color]}"
```

This should work.